# How come I don't have to increment an array pointer whilst allocating values to it

Tags: c, pointers, iteration

I have code to dynamically allocate an array of 100 doubles to a pointer and initialize the memory with values from 1.0 to 100.0.

My question is, in the code below why don't I have to write *ptr++ at each iteration of the for loop. I've tried it and it doesn't work.

```
void allocate_array(){
    double *ptr;
    ptr= (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
    int i=0;
    float j=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        *ptr=j++;
        printf(" %0.1lf\n",*ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to? You're assigning the `0.0, 1.0, ...` values all to the first index of your array. And you never assign anything to the other indices. So you really do output all the values you want, but your array will look like: {99.0, ???, ???, ...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't have to do anything. In your code, you don't initialize the whole array - you just assign 100 different values to its first member. Your code is just like:

```
double d;
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            d=j++;
            printf(" %0.1lf\n",d);
}
```

If you want to initialize the whole array, do something like:

```
double *temp=ptr;
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            *temp=j++;
            printf(" %0.1lf\n",*temp++);
}
```

Comment: @Mat Yes, but the OP asked for `*ptr++`. (That's also why I wrote it in the `printf`)

Comment: but here even, your not iterating *temp each time you assign something to it, why not *temp++=j++ ?

Comment: @EoinMurray I thought that you wanted to print the value before the increment. (You can do it in one line, like `printf(" %0.1lf\n",*temp++=j++);` )

Answer (score 1):

None of this matters, because you aren't returning the pointer to the memory you've allocated; you're just leaking memory.

Try something like this:

```
double *allocate_array(size_t size)
{
  double *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * size); // note no cast, operand of sizeof
  if (ptr)
  {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      ptr[i] = (double) (i+1);  // ptr[0] = 1.0, ptr[1] = 2.0, ptr[2] = 3.0, etc.
    }
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

and you'd call it like

```
double *myArray = allocate_array(100);
```

when you're finished with the array, you need to deallocate it:

```
free(myArray);
```

Note that the one thing you *don't* want to do in `allocate_array` is change the value of `ptr`, at least not without saving that value somewhere else; otherwise, you won't be able to `free` it properly.